# Cross Account SNS subscription by SQS and poll SQS from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a use case to -
create an SNS Topic in a AWS Account, let's say Account "A" and
SQS and Lambda on Account "B".

I have to implement it using CDK (Preferably MonoCDK).
The architecture is SNS --> SQS --> Lambda.
I believe this is a common use case but I am new to these AWS Tools. I would like to know if this is possible and also any implemented resources or tutorials

Comment: Yes, very much possible. There are tons of tutorials on such topics, either with or without CDK available.

Comment: Can you share a few?

Comment: You _might_ have difficulties creating resources in multiple AWS Accounts. Please attempt the process yourself and let us know what _specific_ issue you are facing.